# JPG -> PNG Release outer background

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I do have fowllowing article pics, here as an example a mirror. Of course there can be other geometric forms like bottles, chairs.

The pictures are all in JPEG-format. I want to convert these files to PNG-format. But I want to get rid of the outer white background.

Is there a way to do it by script in php oder ImageMagick?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean to 'magic wand' detect the outline of the object?

Comment: Is this just a screen-grab of your image with poor cutting - or is it the actual image? I am referring to the grey line that almost goes around the edge and isn't quite complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
convert frame.jpg -fuzz 10% -fill none -draw 'color 10,10 floodfill' result.png
```

I have drawn the effect in red here so you can see it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use ImageMagick's `-draw` to isolate a color, and "floodfill" it to transparency.

```
 convert input.jpg \
         -fill transparent \
         -fuzz 20% \
         -draw 'color 15,15 floodfill' \
         out.png
```

See [Color Fill Primitives](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#color) for other great examples.

For PHP's Imagick library, you would do something like...

```php
$img = new Imagick('input.jpg');

$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$draw->setFillColor('transparent');
$draw->color(15,15, Imagick::PAINT_FLOODFILL);

$img->drawImage($draw);
$img->writeImage('out.png');
```